# Getting Error with EIP1559 style transaction: "unrecognized fields: {'maxFeePerGas', 'maxPriorityFeePerGas'}"

Tags: transactions, web3.py, eip-1559

I wanted to sign and send a transaction interacting with a smart contract. This is the tx:

```
Tx = ID.functions.withdraw(50000000000, '0x....').buildTransaction(
    {
    'chainId': 1,
    'gas': 410000,
    'nonce': nonce,  
    'maxFeePerGas': web3.toWei(25, 'gwei'),
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': web3.toWei(2.5, 'gwei')}
    )
```

.withdraw(50000000000, '0x....') is the smart contract function I want to call.

When i sign it:

```
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(Tx, private_key=pk)
```

I get following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\web3\lib\site-packages\eth_account\_utils\transactions.py", line 140, in assert_valid_fields
    raise TypeError("Transaction must not include unrecognized fields: %r" % superfluous_keys)

TypeError: Transaction must not include unrecognized fields: {'maxFeePerGas', 'maxPriorityFeePerGas', 'type'}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is your web3.py version? If you're using pip you can find it via `pip show web3`.

Comment: It says version 5.20.0

Comment: That is your problem, 5.20.0 is a pre-London(EIP 1559) version. You need to update web3.py.